# Create and connect to duckdb on remote

Tags: duckdb, fsspec

`duckdb.connect()` takes a path string and either connects to or creates the duckdb file.

How does one create/connect to a duckdb file on a non-local filesystem?

e.g. I would expect that duckdb supports either

- fsspec paths, like `duckdb.connect("hdfs://...")`
- or had a filesystem parameter like ```duckdb.connect("/mypath", filesystem=myfilesystem)
- or accepts filelike parameters like `with open() as file: duckdb.connect(file)`

Am I missing something or does a duckdb file always have to be on the local filesystem?

Comment: See [Connect](https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.9.2/connect). If you persist a database it is  to a local file.

Comment: More to the point [FAQ Glossary](https://duckdb.org/faq#glossary-of-terms): *In-process database management system: The DBMS runs in the client application’s process instead of running as a separate process, which is common in the traditional client–server setup.  ...*